# catch laravel errorbag $erros in jquery

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can i catch the laravel errorbag in javascript an showing with the sweetalert or something similar. Has onyone tried?

I was thinking catch the variable $errors in a hidden input then with jquery handle it with sweet alert. I am not sure how to do it

This is the {{dump($errors)}} from blade

```
ViewErrorBag {#217 ▼
  #bags: array:1 [▼
    "default" => MessageBag {#218 ▼
      #messages: array:1 [▼
        "searchWord" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The search word field is required when none of vehicle type / transport type / price / out county / out date are present."
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In View do like this. Try to access only required message and store it in a variable called $errors_mes.

```
<input type='hidden' id='error_desc' name='var' value="<?php echo $errors_mes;?>" />
```

and in js file access using id in a following way.

```
var error_desc = $('#error_desc').val();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: using this throws an error in blade: `(3/3) ErrorException
Object of class Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag could not be converted to string`

Comment: (3/3) ErrorException Undefined variable: errors_mes

Comment: @CălinBobeș As I already given in answer try to access the message field in $errors variable and store it in $errors_mes...then the above code will work...